Decay rate of minimum point over a product space
Let $f(\theta, \epsilon)$ be smooth on $[0,2\pi] \times [0,\infty)$ such that

$f(\theta, \epsilon)$ converges to $f(\theta, 0)$ uniformly as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.
$f(\theta, \epsilon) > 0$ for $\epsilon > 0$, $f(\theta, \epsilon)$ has a unique minimum $\theta_{\epsilon}$ with $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2}(\theta_{\epsilon}, \epsilon) > 0$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.
$f(\theta, 0) = (\theta - \theta_0)^2 h(\theta)$ with $h(\theta) > 0$ for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.

Then $f(\theta_{\epsilon}, \epsilon) \rightarrow f(\theta_0, 0) = 0$ and $\theta_{\epsilon} \rightarrow \theta_0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. I wonder if $\theta_{\epsilon} - \theta_0$ can decay arbitrarily slow compared to $f(\theta_{\epsilon}, \epsilon)$ or not. In other words, does there exist a function $f$ satisfying the assumptions above and a subsequence $\epsilon_n \rightarrow 0$ such that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{g(|\theta_{\epsilon_n} - \theta_0|)}{f(\theta_{\epsilon_n}, \epsilon_n)} = \infty
$$
for any function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g(0)=0$ and $g(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$?

$\newcommand\ep\epsilon\newcommand\th\theta$Yes, $|\th_\ep-\th_0|$ can decay arbitrarily slowly compared to $f(\th_\ep,\ep)$.
Indeed, let $g\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be any smooth function such that $g(0)=0$ and $g(x)>0$ for $x>0$. Suppose that $f(\th,\ep)=(\th-\ep)^2+\ep g(\ep)$ for $\th\in[0,2\pi]$ and real $\ep\ge0$. Then all your conditions on $f$ hold, with $\th_\ep=\ep$ and $f(\th_\ep,\ep)=\ep g(\ep)$, so that
$$\frac{g(|\th_\ep-\th_0|)}{f(\th_\ep,\ep)}=\frac{g(\ep)}{\ep g(\ep)}\to\infty$$
as $\ep\downarrow0$.

Thank you for your answer. But the questions asks for the existence of an $f$ for which the limit is infinity for any $g$. In your example $f$ depend on $g$, and the limit will not be infinity if one takes $g'=\sqrt{g}$.

@MathLearner : Then the question would not make any sense. For instance, one can always let $g$ be such that $g(|\theta_{\epsilon_n}-\th_0|)=f(\theta_{\epsilon_n},\epsilon_n)$ for some $\epsilon_n\to0$.

I don't think so. Please note that $f(\theta_{\epsilon_n}, \epsilon_n)$ is not a function of the form $g(|\theta_{\epsilon_n}-\theta_0|)$ for some real valued function $g$.

@MathLearner : Think again. You have $\theta_\epsilon\to\theta_0$ as $\epsilon\downarrow0$. So, you can pick a sequence $(\epsilon_n)$ converging down to $0$ such that $\theta_{\epsilon_n}$ converges to $\theta_0$ monotonically. So, for each large enough $n$ you can define $g(|\theta_{\epsilon_n}-\theta_0|)$ as $f(\theta_{\epsilon_n},\epsilon_n)$ and then extend this definition of $g$ to an entire right neighborhood of $0$ by (say) linear interpolation.

Thank you losif. I had a follow up question which I added in the body of the question. I would appreciate if you could take a look at it and let me know what you think. Thank you so much. I truly appreciate the time that you have spent answering my question:)

@MathLearner : At this point, I don't know an answer to this latter question, but I will have it in mind. You may want to post this latter question separately. And I think this edit is not appropriate, after both versions of your question (the one initially intended and the one perceived) have been answered.

Thank you. I will remove the edit and make a new post.

Here is the new post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/469362/rate-of-convergence-of-the-minimum-point-over-a-product-space
